# Elm drawing over list

Tags: elm

I am trying to draw a list of objects but cannot get it to work.
Secondary question is how do I make a "for loop" using ELM.

I have a

```
type Object a = { a | x:Float, y:Float, vx:Float, vy:Float }
type Car  = Object {}
type Cars = [Car]

displayCar =  move (car.x,car.y) (filled white (rect 30 20))
displayCars = ?????
```

I am trying to get somethign liek this to work

```
collage 100 100 [displayCar (head cars) -- does work
                 , displayCars cars -- does not work

                ]
```

In particular, the collage has multiple things it needs to plot:

```
   [ filled pongGreen   (rect gameWidth gameHeight)
   , displayObjHouse (game.houses !! 0) -- so ugly code
   , displayObjHouse (game.houses !! 1) -- so ugly code
   , displayObjHouse (game.houses !! 2) -- so ugly code
   , displayObjHouse (game.houses !! 3) -- so ugly code
   , displayObjHouse (game.houses !! 4) -- so ugly code
   , displayCars cars -- does not work  
   ]
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the function [`map`](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.13/List#map).

`map : (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`

This means that you can apply some function to a list of things and get back a list of the results.

You are very close with what you have here. I've filled in some blanks to help you keep making progress! Good luck!

```
type Object a = { a | x:Float, y:Float, vx:Float, vy:Float }
type Car = Object {}
type House = Object { residents : Int }

displayCar : Car -> Form
displayCar car =  move (car.x,car.y) (filled black (rect 30 20))

displayCars : [Car] -> [Form]
displayCars cars = map displayCar cars

-- map : (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
-- In our particular example, we plug in our functions
-- displayCar : Car -> Form
-- since display car is the first argument to map, all a's become Car
-- and all b's become Form
-- So the type of map in this instance is ((Car -> Form) -> [Car] -> [Form]

someCars : [Car]
someCars = [ { x = 100, y = 10, vx = 0, vy = 0 }
           , { x = 35, y = 100, vx = 0, vy = 0 }
           , { x = 0, y = 0, vx = 0, vy = 0 }
           ]

someHouses : [House]
someHouses = [ { x = 20, y = -100, vx = 0, vy = 0, residents = 3 }
             , { x = -20, y = -50, vx = 0, vy = 0, residents = 3 }
             , { x = 160, y = -150, vx = 0, vy = 0, residents = 3 }
             ]  

displayHouse : House -> Form
displayHouse house = move (house.x, house.y) (filled blue (rect 30 50))

main : Element
main = 
  let houses = map displayHouse someHouses
      cars   = map displayCar someCars
  in collage 400 400 (houses ++ cars)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when yuo are plotting different objects.  To clarify.  I have another list to show, say it's another list of cars.
main = collage 400 400 [(displayCars someCars)] ++ [displayCars someCars2] 

this doesn't work.  not sure why.  Also it's not two sets of cars I need to show, but other types of objects :( I came across the map, but couldn't get it to work

Comment: It looks like it is an order of evaluation issue here. Does it work if you do `main = collage 400 400 ([(displayCars someCars)] ++ [displayCars someCars2])`?

Comment: Also, Elms type system won't let you have a list containing two different types. However, assuming you have display functions for each type, you should be able to use `map` to convert each to a `[Form]` and then combine those lists.

Comment: I've updated the example to show how you might do houses and cars.